# Update if row > 0 OR INSERT on Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How to I can create a query for update, if select result is bigger then 0, else execute insert?

I had try execute this code, but is not work

```
select
    case
        where count(id) > 0 (update product set description = 'blablabla' where id_fk1 = 3 AND id_fk2 = 4)
        else (insert into product (description) values('blablabla')
    end
```

I know this is a select code, it will not work, but I don't know how to use If in mysql

Answer (score 0):

you can use this example  [foreign-keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)
there is a way to compose single query which compose single query with 'update ...' and 'insert into...'
or, if i misunderstood you, you can use this one [insert-on-duplucate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is INSERT with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: I can not use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, because my check condition is not Unique key column and I no have id of registers, is a combination of 2 columns (exemple: update tb1 set c1 = 'v1' where id_fk1 = 2 and id_fk2 = 3); not update tb1 set c1 = 'v1' where id = 3

Comment: I see. I don't think this is possible with a single statement then.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before:
[Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-to-table-or-update-if-exists-mysql)

Contains many interesting answers.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want to insert the paid `id = 3, description = 'blablabla'` into the table.  If it exists, then update the description.

You can use `insert . . . on duplicate key insert`, assuming that `id` is declared as the primary key or as a unique key.  You would do this as:

```
create unique key product_id on product(id);
```

Then the following statement does what you want:

```
insert into product(id, description)
    select 3, 'blablabla'
    on duplicate key insert description = values(description);
```

EDIT:

I think the same idea applies to two foreign keys:

```
create unique key product_fk1_fk2 on product(id_fk1, id_fk2);

insert into product(id_fk1, id_fk2, description)
    select 3, 4, 'blablabla'
    on duplicate key insert description = values(description);
```

Comment: sorry for my bad expression, but I can not apply unique key for product_id, because this column is a many to one foreign key (product 1 - n tb2)

Answer (score 0):

It will be base on the number of your query result, right?

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM product");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0){

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO product (description) VALUES ('blah')");

}

else {

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE product SET description='blah'");

}
```

If you're trying to base it on your id field, try this:

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM product");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0){

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO product (description) VALUES ('blah')");

}

else 

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

$id=$row['id'];

if($id>0){
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE product SET description='blah' WHERE id='$id'");
}

} /* END OF WHILE LOOP */

} /* END OF ELSE */
```